# Exception and Array in java

Tags: java

Write a program to create a user defined exception name VoterEligibility exception. Create a Demo Class which show that: If a voter is less than 18 then throw VoterEligibility exception else issue the voter card.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyException extends Exception{
    MyException(String msg){
        super(msg);
}
}

class Voting{

int age;
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("Enter the number of voters:");
        num=s.nextInt();
    }
    while((num<0)&&(num==0));

    Voting[] v=new Voting[num];
    int i=0;

    for(int j:v){
        System.out.println("Enter the age of "+ ++i +" element:");
        j=s.nextInt();
        check(j);
    }
}

static void check(int age){
    try{
        if(age<18)
            throw new MyException("You are underage");
        else return;
    }
    catch(MyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
}


static void check(int age){
    try{
        if(age<18)
            throw new MyException("You are underage");
        else return;
    }
    catch(MyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.msg();
    }
}
}
```

Here there are number of errors on compiling please help me with errors

```
raj421@421SD:~/data/java$ javac Voters.java

Voters.java:5: error: constructor Exception in class Exception cannot be applied to given types;

super(msg);

    ^

  required: no arguments

 found: String

 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Voters.java:25: error: incompatible types: Voting cannot be converted to int

```
    for(int j:v){

              ^
```

Voters.java:35: error: incompatible types: MyException cannot be converted to 
Throwable

```
            throw new MyException("You are underage");

            ^
```

Voters.java:38: error: incompatible types: MyException cannot be converted to 
Throwable

```
    catch(MyException e){

          ^
```

Voters.java:39: error: cannot find symbol

```
        e.printStackTrace();

         ^
```

symbol:   method printStackTrace()

location: variable e of type MyException

Voters.java:40: error: cannot find symbol

```
        e.getMessage();

         ^
```

symbol:   method getMessage()

location: variable e of type MyException

6 errors

Comment: `javac Voters.java` ? but your class's name is `Voting`.

Answer (score 2):

Your exception's constructor should pass its parameter to the super class :

```
class MyException extends Exception{
    MyException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

There's no need to store the `msg` in your class, as it is already stored in `Throwable`, and can be accessed with `getMessage()`.

You should replace `e.msg()` with `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: I have updated the code and its saying that Exception class does not takes any arguments

Comment: @RohanChauhan java.lang.Exception has a constructor that takes a String argument - `public Exception(String message)`. Is it possible you created your own class named `Exception` which hides `java.lang.Exception`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are many error, the first one is on the for loop, you can't use the standard foor loop in this way:

```
 for(int j:v){
    System.out.println("Enter the age of "+ ++i +" element:");
    j=s.nextInt();
    check(j);
}
```

because is a array that stores objects reference of Voting class and not int. The second one is that you have two method check with the same signature, and javac dosen't allow this, another problem is during the use of array v, you have declared and allocated the array but you have to also initialize the array objects,  finally the way to manage the exception is very bad for me. Now i modified your code and now it works

```
package org.senzacontrollo.designPatterns;

import java.util.Scanner;

class MyException extends Exception{
    MyException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}

class Voting{

int age;
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("Enter the number of voters:");
        num=s.nextInt();
    }
    while((num<0)&&(num==0));

    //Definition and allocation 
    Voting[] v=new Voting[num];

    //Init
    for(int i = 0 ; i<v.length ; i++){
        Voting vtemp = new Voting();
        v[i] = vtemp;
    }



    int i=0;

    for(Voting v1:v){
        System.out.println("Enter the age of "+ ++i +" element:");
        v1.age=s.nextInt();
        check(v1.age);
    }
}

static void check(int age){
    try{
        if(age<18)
            throw new MyException("You are underage");
        else return;
    }
    catch(MyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
}
```